# Corpses controlled by live operators fighting gladiatorially/ring style

Tags: story-identification

Does anybody remember a short novel or story about a guy who's the controller/operator of a fighting corpse? I seem to remember him visiting a whorehouse-type establishment and thinking he'd love to meet the controller of the corpses used for that function, then being told those corpses are automated...

Comment: Couldn't you describe any person as an 'automated corpse'?

Comment: They aren't so much automated as controlled by the...partaker's unconscious mind.

Comment: There's a somewhat similar theme in Peter Hamilton's "Sonnie's Edge" (published as part of the Second Chance at Eden) collection.

Answer (score 4):

[Meathouse Man](http://www.johnjosephadams.com/the-living-dead/?page_id=43) by George R. R. Martin (link is to an exerpt from the story as published in *The Living Dead*)

From an Amazon review for the book [*The Living Dead*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1597801437).

> Meathouse Man by George R. R. Martin; a sad short story by one of my
>   favorite authors, featuring a young man who can run corpses to do
>   multiple jobs, but all he wants his to find his true love. His search
>   takes him to many jobs, many worlds, and to the meathouse, where
>   corpses respond to his needs. A sad tale, but as always well paced
>   with a well brought out leading character.

I recall the story well.  He ends up 'driving' corpses in the gladiator games at one point, and the 'meathouse' plays a big part in the early sections of the story.